# Mouse stops working, only able to click on dock, ends up in crash

Tags: gnome, 18.04

In Ubuntu 18.04 I've had a reoccurring issue of the mouse randomly ceasing to function.

When that happens, I am unable to click anywhere but the Dock. I've had the same problem with numerous different mouses.

When it happened this time around, I decided to put my laptop to sleep and unplug the mouse to see if that'll hopefully fix it. When I opened the lid, GNOME crashed and my session was gone.

I'm attaching a 30 minute snapshot of the contents of `journalctl` of around the time it occurred. The mouse stopped responding somewhere around 15:32-35; I put the laptop to sleep at around 15:37, and the session crashed at around 15:39 upon opening the lid.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/UnMkzCtK

Comment: What GNOME extensions do you have installed/enabled? **Workspaces to Dock** perhaps?

Comment: Dash to Dock, Hide Activities Button, Frippery Move Clock and Pixel Saver.

Also enabled is the System extension Ubuntu AppIndicators.

Comment: Temporarily disable ALL GNOME extensions, except turn ON the Ubuntu Dock and Ubuntu Appindicators. See if it makes any difference.

Comment: Also temporarily turn off any startup apps... like Spotify... which crashed. Make sure you have the latest ATI Radeon video driver software. Make sure that `intel-microcode` and `amd-microcode` are installed. Make sure you have the latest BIOS firmware installed for your manufacturer. I'm going into the hospital today, so I may not be able to follow up immediately, but please do keep me posted.

Comment: I have managed to narrow it down, after a clean install of Ubuntu, and believe it is an instance of this Critical 6 year old bug. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mutter/+bug/1181666

Comment: You should try 19.10 and see if the problem still exists. Report back to @heynnema